# How to stop com.yammer.dropwizard.Service remotely

Tags: java, jetty, jmx, dropwizard

I have a main program running as an instance of com.yammer.dropwizard.Service

```
        SystemInformationService extends Service<SystemInformationConfiguration>
```

Trying to programmatically stop the Jetty service from a remote process. I have tried to use the JMX messaging service but do not see a stop method available when I look at the MBeans through jconsole.  Code I have tried, but get a javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server:type=server,id=0 exception is below

```
        String JMX_URL = "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:9095/jmxrmi";
        System.out.println("Shutting down Jetty instance");

        JMXConnector connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(new JMXServiceURL(JMX_URL), null);
        connector.connect();
        MBeanServerConnection connection = connector.getMBeanServerConnection();
        ObjectName on = new ObjectName("org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server:type=server,id=0");
        connection.invoke(on, "stop", null, null);
        System.out.println("Shutdown command sent");
        return new AgentStatus(ApplicationStatus.OFFLINE);
```

Note also that the service was launched with these flags

```
       -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9095 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

Comment: This issue was resolved by using the information on this article https://gist.github.com/dguardado/d1e105a9374b1111a064

Comment: You could write an answer to your own question and highlight the differences between the code in the question and the mentioned article. This way when someone searches the site he will see that there is an answer to this question. You could also accept your own answer :)